# How can I infer TypeScript return type based on an argument that extends another generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function returning a function:

```js
type OuterFunction<OuterParams extends [...any], InnerParams extends [...any]> = 
  (outerParams: [...OuterParams]) => (innerParams: [...InnerParams]) => Promise<boolean>
```

I am trying to create another function that receives an `OuterFunction` and `OuterParams` and returns
the inner function:

```js
type OuterParamsOf<T> = T extends OuterFunction<infer Deps, any[]> ? Deps : never

function someFunction<T extends OuterFunction<any[], any[]>>(func: T, deps: [...OuterParamsOf<T>]): ReturnType<T> {
  return func(...deps)
}
```

But I get this, and I'm not sure exactly why:

```
Type '(...args: any[]) => Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T>'
```

How can I set the return type based on the `func` parameter? Why do I get this error?

By the way, Ignoring the error and just calling `someFunction` works well.

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBB5ArnEMBiWAdgMZwCWURAPACIgQDOC4uRAJswNoB0fAhkWQBdADQIAkkSJ5CpClQAK-GPwC2zViA7c+PQSIB8CALwIAFMAQI97BowBcCek2ABKU8fN6VAc0eS0rLEZJREyqoaHibGijBQauSMINQARlBQADYggobAwChomDh4EeqMGABm1AAqxmY1LGBsnMW4BCEKNORElXjO9uIGXMLGAPwDTAhOMgBuePmVnWEIjAkgcqFUtU0tzNjtm13Uw2IIp4aG5kukTjXidkxOvHwHpSrlVbWGwm5OAEogOBYGBEGqoFJ1BAAbysCBgQJBRAQNxI3j4j0YbmAAF9gEA)

Comment: The type checker cannot do much type analysis on conditional types that depend on generic type parameters, like `OuterParamsOf<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` inside the body of `someFunction`.  (See [ms/TS#42493](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42493) for example.)  If you can avoid such types, you should.  I'd refactor your example to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NDDGVN), if you want better type analysis.  Does this fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't inline this type definition - this is a simplified version of more complex types. `OuterFunction` is being used in other places as well.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to specify that? Actually it would be even better if you could edit the code example to motivate it; if it’s too simple to show why you need it, you might want to make it a little more complex.